# Calling an extension method from a child component

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a Visualforce component issue that I cannot resolve.

**VF page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="MyExtension">
    <c:childComponent />
</apex:page>
```

**Child component:**

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandLink value="Cancel" action="{!doCancel}"></apex:commandLink>
    </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

**Extension class:**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension {
    public Id recordId;

    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.recordId = stdController.getId();
    }

    public PageReference doCancel() {
        return new PageReference('/' + this.recordId);
    }
}
```

I need the command link in the child component to call the `doCancel()` method in the parent page's extension's class.

Is this possible?

Comment: +1 for a nice MVR of the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to modify your component markup

```
<apex:component>
  <apex:attribute name="cancelAction" type="ApexPages.Action" required="true"/> 
  <apex:form>
    <apex:commandLink value="Cancel" action="{!cancelAction}" immediate="true"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

and then reference the component as such:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="MyExtension">
  <c:childComponent cancelAction="{!doCancel}"/>
</apex:page>
```

*Hat tip to Keir Bowden and his seminal book Visualforce Development Cookbook  2nd Edition p. 51*

**How this works:**

You are passing to the component an object of type `ApexPages.Action`. A rarely-used explicit object type but especially handy in this use case.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks a lot!